# How many number of MapReduce Jobs are used by Hive in a join?

Tags: hive, hiveql

1. Suppose we have four tables Employee , Department, Location, Skills, table. We fire a query in Hive:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Department 
JOIN Employee ON (Department.emp_id =Employee.emp_id) 
JOIN Location ON (Employee.location_id =Location.location_id) 
JOIN (Employee.skill_code = Skills.skill_code)`
```

How many Mapreduce Jobs will run in this case? *

2. If the above query is modified as

```
SELECT * 
FROM Department 
JOIN Employee ON (Department.emp_id =Employee.emp_id) 
JOIN Location ON (Employee.location_id =Location.location_id) 
JOIN (Employee.emp_id = Skills.emp_id)`.
```

How many Mapreduce Jobs will run in this case?

Is the answer 3? Always the `number joins = Number of Mappers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood, join operations are MapReduce jobs and one join column internally gets converted to one MapReduce job, and it never depends on the number of joins.

> SELECT * FROM Department JOIN Employee ON (Department.emp_id
> = Employee.emp_id) JOIN Location ON (Employee.location_id = Location.location_id) JOIN (Employee.skill_code = Skills.skill_code)

1. There are 3 different joining-columns (emp_id, location_id, skill_code) is used, in the above query, so there will be 3 MR jobs for it.

> SELECT * FROM Department JOIN Employee ON (Department.emp_id
> = Employee.emp_id) JOIN Location ON (Employee.location_id = Location.location_id) JOIN (Employee.emp_id = Skills.emp_id)

2. There are 2 different joining-columns (emp_id, location_id) is used, in the above query, so there will be 2 MR jobs for it.